# logstash output for arangodb

Tags: logstash, arangodb

did somebody alrady find an output package for logstash to arangodb? I see that there is one to elasticsearch which probably is quite similar, maybe also to mongodb. But unfortunately I up-to-now didn't find one for arangodb, and the public logstash documentation doesn't help me, as I'm not familiar with ruby.

Comment: As far as I can see here (https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash-contrib/tree/master/lib/logstash/outputs), there isn't yet a contributed output package for ArangoDB. It looks like the output plugin for InfluxDB (https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash-contrib/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/influxdb.rb) could be a good start for a dedicated ArangoDB plugin. It uses ftw, so it can probably be adapted to use other HTTP APIs easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I gave it a try and found the generic [logstash http output plugin](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-http) to be able to connect to ArangoDB. I wrote a blog article about [using ArangoDB as a Logstash output](http://jsteemann.github.io/blog/2015/02/05/using-arangodb-as-a-logstash-output/) with this plugin.

Compared with a dedicated ArangoDB plugin this has the advantage that it is already available and seems to be maintained by logstash as one of the standard plugins.

Comment: YES, WORKS! And THANK YOU!. Last night I had the same idea ... but your explanation, observation and first additional hints (e.g. about access rights, possible pitfalls) help me to find my way. Great work!

Answer (score 0):

It's work fine^

bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin {codec => "json"  } }  output { http { http_method => "post" url => "http://127.0.0.1:8529/_db/rest/_api/document?collection=rest" format => "json"  headers => [ "Authorization", "Basic cm9vdDpwYXNzd29yZA==" ] } }'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).